# Getting UserId of current user Blazor webassembly

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

So I am writing a Blazor webassembly application, with asp.ner core Identity. I need to get the ID of the current user, not the username that the methods in Identy give.

The method

Context. User.identity.name

gives the username but I need the ID for a fk in a model/table.

I can't use the username as usernames might change.

I have searched the net, however I keep seeing just the username returned.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: None of these answeres have helped me, why is it so complex just to get the user id?

Comment: I fully agree with you. I am also looking for a solution. But the the suggested ones are more complex then my real code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use this with the boiler plate Identity Server:

```
@page "/claims"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

<h3>ClaimsPrincipal Data</h3>

<p>@_authMessage</p>

@if (_claims.Count() > 0)
{
    <table class="table">
        @foreach (var claim in _claims)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@claim.Type</td>
                <td>@claim.Value</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}

<p>@_userId</p>

@code {
    private string _authMessage;       
    private string _userId;
    private IEnumerable<Claim> _claims = Enumerable.Empty<Claim>();

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        await GetClaimsPrincipalData();
        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    private async Task GetClaimsPrincipalData()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
            _claims = user.Claims;
            _userId = $"User Id: {user.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value}";
        }
        else
        {
            _authMessage = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend extracting the Id in the controller though, as this is more secure than trusting a clients post contents.

Comment: @ErikThysell this is an extension method for the principle.

Comment: The OP wanted the ID and not the Name... What claim is "sub" supposed to be?

Comment: @Nanoserver For some reason "sub" is the claim for the UserId when working in client side blazor wasm. It's server equivalent being ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier. There's probably a reason for this, Im just not aware of it

Answer (score 8):

In Startup.cs, add the following line in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

In your Blazor component, add the following lines on the top of the file

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
```

In your method, add the following lines to get the UserId

```
var principal = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
var loggedInUserId = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Comment: This did the perfect trick on Blazor Server dotnet 5

Comment: Is this for WASM or server side?

Comment: Trying it in Blazor WebAssembly Client side, always HttpContext is null.

Comment: does not work in wasm, the question was specific for blazor wasm

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, just a tip on using breakpoints to find the answer.  My site is Blazor Server, so it's very possible that things are different-- in my case, Brian Parker's solution didn't work for me, so I did the following:

```
var user = (await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
if (true) {} // or any other code here, breakpoint this line
```

If you set a breakpoint right after retrieving the user, run the app and hover the user variable in the code when it breaks, it will pop up the complete object.  By hovering various fields, you can investigate.  I found that the claim type strings were big long things like "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"

So the answer that worked for me was:

```
var user = (await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
string userId = user.FindFirst(c => c.Type.Contains("nameidentifier"))?.Value;
```

My point is that when the docs are complicated, or when the technology is changing fast so that one day's right answer is the next day's wrong lead, you can achieve a lot just by using VS to dig around.

Hope that helps someone. :D

Comment: For me, only this answer worked. However, I have one small complaint. The check should not be done by string but by claim. See example:  `c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`

Comment: Yeah, I figured the above on my own without knowing anything about Claims at all.  It's still just a string comparison either way, but your way looks a little cleaner semantically.